# Unit test case not covering tap and switchMap under concat Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine

Unit test is not covering for rxjs (tap, concat, switchMap). Please find below image and code details.

```
 this.items$ = concat(
  of([]), // default items
  this.input$.pipe(
    filter((res) => {
      return res !== null && res.length >= 2;
    }),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(200),
    tap(() => (this.itemsLoading = true)),
    switchMap((term) => {
      return this.globalSearchService.getEndUser(term).pipe(
        catchError(() => of([])), // empty list on error
        tap(() => (this.itemsLoading = false))
      );
    })
  )
);
```

[Coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihaiI.jpg)

Comment: It looks like your chain emits an error but it's impossible to tell why

Comment: seems like your `this.input$` doesn't emit anything that meet the conditions in the `filter` operator: `return res !== null && res.length >= 2`.